# PowerAutomate - Docusign Integration

Tags: power-automate

Does anyone get this code when connecting to DocuSign Triggers?  I purchased the DocuSign Pro account and although I can connect I keep getting this error when I am trying to use the DocuSign trigger with PowerAutomate.

{"errorCode":"ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS","message":"This Account lacks sufficient permissions. Connect not enabled for account."}}

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right credentials for that connector?

Answer (score 0):

What type of account did you get? I have dealt with DocuSign a lot recently and they have different packages and tiers with different options.  I believe the API access is part of the 'Advanced Workflow' functions that need to be purchased separately

Hope this helps